# A verb for fluid rushing out in small amount

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a verb to describe fluid rushing out from an opening *in small amount*?

"Gush out" sounds like in huge amount. "Seeps through" on the other hand lacks the force that brought the fluid out, like with in "gush".

Comment: Can you name any real-world examples where such a thing might occur? It seems a very odd juxtaposition of things. Normally, if the fluid is coming out with a force large enough to warrant calling it ‘rushing’, the amount of fluid does not really matter that much—it is relative. For example, blood can be gushing out from a wound, even though the entire amount of blood gushed out is minimal compared to the amount of water, say, spewed from a broken water pipe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the verbs *[jet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jet#Verb)*, *[spray](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spray#Verb)*, and *[stream](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stream#Verb)*.  For example,  “A fine stream of water jetted from the pinhole” implies small amounts of liquid spraying out under high pressure.

Answer (score 7):

**[Trickle](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/trickle)** - (of a liquid) flow in a small stream.

Usage: "A solitary tear trickled down her cheek."

OR

**[Spurt](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spurt)** - A sudden short burst, as of energy, activity, or growth.

Usage: "The pus spurted onto the mirror."

Answer (score 5):

For "small amount" use [*drip*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drip):

> To fall in drops: Water is dripping from that leaky faucet.

You're right that *seep* (not sip) implies a passive and slow movement, with no force suggested. If you want a word for "small amounts of water rushing out", I can only think of [*leak*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leak). A leak does not necessarily need high pressure but it *can* have it:

> to let a liquid, gas, light, etc., enter or escape, as through an unintended hole or crack.

If you are referring to a pressurized container with a small hole, I would recommend *escaping*.

The problem is that if a liquid is *rushing* out, it is rarely doing so in small quantities.

Answer (score 1):

**Dribbling or dripping**

Usage: "The water is barely dribbling out of the faucet."

Answer (score 1):

Squirt or stream might work depending on exact context

Answer (score 1):

I like jwpat7's suggestion of *stream* best.

Another apt alternative is to say ***course*** meaning to run or flow swiftly as in this dictionary example:

> *The blood of ancient emperors courses through his veins.*
>
> ***course***
>   verb [I usually + adv/prep]       /kɔːs/  US  /kɔːrs/ formal
>
> Definition
>   › to flow quickly or in large amounts:
>   *Tears were coursing down his cheeks.*
>
> *You could almost hear the blood coursing through her veins as she passed the finishing line.*

Alternative verbs for slow movement of fluids are:

***flow***

***undulate***

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised *leak* was not higher in the list. That is the word most obvious to me. I associate it with a relatively low rate of flow relative to the total volume of what is being leaked.

> We paddled quickly to shore after our boat sprung a
>   leak.
>
> [lēk] verb (of a container or covering) accidentally lose or admit contents, especially liquid or gas, through a hole or crack

Oh. I see @terdon did mention it.

Comment: Since, as you mention, **leak** has already been mentioned, was it really worth answering?

Comment: Yes. @terdon made *drip* his primary answer; *leak* was mine. I gave him credit for including what I considered the better answer.